# Having Trouble with Bash RegEx and Grep – Need Assistance

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Im trying to write a bash script that uses a RegEx pattern and takes this as input:

```
  #
  #------------------------------------------- spaceholder ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #

  #@E2E-1 @id:1 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  #@E2E-2 @id:32 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message


  #
  #------------------------------------------- B2B_PKG_3PA ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


  #

  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```

and I tested it with this chatgpt generated Pattern: `((@[^\n]+|#@[^\n]+)?\s*)?Scenario:[^\n]*\n(?:[^\n]*\n)*?\n`

and it works just like how I want and the output looks like this on a RegEx testing Website:

```
  #@E2E-1 @id:1 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  #@E2E-2 @id:32 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```

so now I tried it with grep in bash like this:

```bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' block; do
        current_scenarios+=("$block")
    done < <(grep -Pzo "$pattern" "$current_file")
```

and for some reason it include the #space holder part, Ive tried `grep -E`, `grep -oP`, `grep -Po` but nothing seems to work, please help

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- Each block starts with the line beginning with `#@` or `@`.
- The next line in the block starts with the string `Scenario:`.
- A block does not contain blank lines in between.
- A block ends if followed by two or more blank lines (or the end of the file).
- You want to assign a bash array `current_scenarios` with the matched blocks.
- Each line of `$current_file` looks containing two leading whitespaces,
  but this is an editing issue and can be ignored.

Then would you please try:

```
pattern="(?sm)^#?@[^\n]+\n*^Scenario:.*?\n(?=\n{2}|\n*\Z)"
while IFS= read -r -d '' block; do
    current_scenarios+=("$block")
done < <(grep -Pzo "$pattern" "$current_file")

printf "%s\n\n" "${current_scenarios[@]}"       # just to see the results
```

Explanation of the regex `(?sm)^#?@[^\n]+\n*^Scenario:.*?\n(?=\n{2}|\n*\Z)`:

- The `(?s)` option makes a dot `.` match a newline.
- The `(?m)` option makes `^` and `$` match start/end of the line,
  as well as the start/end of the input string.
- `^#?@` matches either `#@` or `@` at the start of the line.
- `[^\n]+\n*` consumes current line.
- `^Scenario:` matches the next line.
- `.*?\n` matches following lines as short as possible (non-greedy).
- `(?=\n{2}|\n*\Z)` is a lookahead assertion which matches two blank
  lines or the end of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind [this quote](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Any regexp you generate or validate online is not guaranteed to work with every command line tool, and if it's a complicated regexp, especially one you want to span multiple input lines, then there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you want.

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$1 ~ /^#?@/' file
  #@E2E-1 @id:1
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message

  #@E2E-2 @id:32
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message

  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```